# How to put a switch statement inside another switch statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

Im trying to work out a quote value after a user makes a selection in 2 select boxes.

It looks like 1 need 2 switch statements. Is this possible? (There are a lot more possible values than the ones below. I've deleted them for the sake of clarity)

```
 var workOutQuote = function() {
        var value1 = $("#delivery_from_area").val();
        var value2 = $("#delivery_to_area").val();
        var val = '';
            switch (value1)
            { case '1':
                { switch (value2)
                    { case '1': val="90"; break; }
                    { case '2': val="80"; break; }
                    { case '3': val="70"; break; }
                }
            }
            { case '2':
                { switch (value2)
                    { case '1': val="80"; break; }
                    { case '2': val="90"; break; }
                    { case '3': val="70"; break; }
                }
            }
}
```

Using the code above I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token case
```

Comment: The `{` after the switch should contain all cases, not be closed for each case; `switch(xxx) { case a: ... case b: ... }`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use **`BREAK`** , if you **`don't want to call all case`**.
Otherwise ,you will get unexpected Results

```
 var workOutQuote = function() {
        var value1 = $("#delivery_from_area").val();
        var value2 = $("#delivery_to_area").val();
        var val = '';
            switch (value1){ 
            case '1':
                 switch (value2){
                     case '1': val="90"; break; 
                     case '2': val="80"; break; 
                     case '3': val="70"; break; 
                }

            break;
            case '2':
                 switch (value2){
                     case '1': val="80"; break; 
                     case '2': val="90"; break; 
                     case '3': val="70"; break; 
                }
                break;             
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are putting case in `braces`, an example from your code `{ case '1': val="90"; break; }`

```
    var value1 = '2';
    var value2 = '2';
    var val = '';
    switch (value1) {
        case '1':
            {
                switch (value2) {
                    case '1':
                        val = "90";
                        break;

                    case '2':
                        val = "80";
                        break;

                    case '3':
                        val = "70";
                        break;
                }
            }
        case '2':
            {
                switch (value2) {
                    case '1':
                        val = "80";
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        val = "90";
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        val = "70";
                        break;
                }
            }
    }
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uL6cf/)

Answer (score 3):

The excessive use of braces is causing the *statement* after the `switch ()` (that javascript grammar mandates you to include) to end early. Adjust to this:

```
        switch (value1){
        case '1':
            switch (value2){
                case '1': val="90"; break;
                case '2': val="80"; break;
                case '3': val="70"; break;
            }
            break;            
        case '2':
            switch (value2){
                case '1': val="80"; break;
                case '2': val="90"; break;
                case '3': val="70"; break;
            }
            break;
       }
```

I've also taken the liberty of putting a `break;` between your outer cases since, at present your first case runs into the next one.

The final `break` I added (right at the bottom) is there for clarity: many folk would not include this.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put brackets around each case :

```
        switch (value1)
        { case '1':
            { switch (value2)
                { case '1': val="90"; break; }
                { case '2': val="80"; break; }
```

Should be :

```
        switch (value1)
        { case '1':
            switch (value2) {
                 case '1': val="90"; break; 
                 case '2': val="80"; break; 
            }
        }
```